# How to perform Drag and Drop using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to do drag and drop. I got the idea from this [Jquery Link](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists).

My code also working fine, if I apply the same code without changing anything. Now I want to **change the ID name of UI tag**. Once I changed, the drag and drop is not working.

Here is my code

**Aspx code**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ColumnNamesSortable, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#ColumnNamesSortable,
#sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #846868;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#ColumnNamesSortable li,
#sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px!important;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  width: 155px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="ColumnNamesSortable" class="connectedSortable"> //change id name from sortable1 to ColumnNamesSortable (not working)
  <li class="ui-state-default">StoreID</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ItemLookupCode</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ExtendedDescription</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">SubDescription1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Department</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Category</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">SupplierCode</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">SupplierName</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">TotalQuantity</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ExtendedPrice</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ExtendedCost</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Profit</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">UnitOfMeasure</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">CustomerAccountNumber</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">CustomerName</li>
</ul>
<br />
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable"> // this one is working
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to create four drag and drop. For example

1. `ColumnNamesSortable`
2. `DataField`
3. `ColumnField`
4. `RowField`

Why when I change the name of Id of particular tag it's not working. And it doesn't show any error on console.

Comment: What ID are you trying to change?

Comment: @Barmar Can't you in the comment line of my first line code?. `ColumnNamesSortable`  This is one name

Comment: I converted your question to an executable snippet, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example. Any sortable `li` can be dragged and dropped into another.

Just add all the id's to the selector and instantiate `sortable`.

```
$("#ColumnNamesSortable, #sortable2, #ColumnField, #RowField").sortable({
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ColumnNamesSortable, #sortable2, #ColumnField, #RowField").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="ColumnNamesSortable" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">StoreID</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ItemLookupCode</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ExtendedDescription</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">SubDescription1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Department</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Category</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">SupplierCode</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">SupplierName</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">TotalQuantity</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ExtendedPrice</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">ExtendedCost</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Profit</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">UnitOfMeasure</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">CustomerAccountNumber</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">CustomerName</li>
</ul>
<br />
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
<br />
<ul id="ColumnField" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ColumnField 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ColumnField 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ColumnField 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ColumnField 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">ColumnField 5</li>
</ul>
<br />
<ul id="RowField" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">RowField 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">RowField 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">RowField 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">RowField 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">RowField 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Barmar : Updated the answer.

Comment: He has the changed ID in his `.sortable()` call. I don't see any difference between your answer and his code, except that you added more lists.